# Javascript slideToggle animation stops early

Tags: javascript, transition

I'm making this menu when you click a list item drops down. It works fine but the animation stop prematurely and instantly drops down. I don't know much about javascript so can you tell me the problem here?

```
$('.mobile-menu a#toggle').click(function() {
  $('ul').slideToggle(300, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Make your code a reproducible snippet (CTRL+M in the editor) so that we can troubleshoot your problem

Comment: So it finishes before 300 milliseconds are up? Please also post the relevant markup, prayerfully in in a working snippet demonstrating the problem so we can see what might be the cause. Also see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)